# Program in docker logging with syslog does not generate log files

Tags: docker, syslog

I am using a centos 7.9 for my docker.   I'm running a C++ program in my docker image which writes logging via syslog.
However, I cannot find these log anywhere when I run it in docker.   On my centos machine, the logging would by default go to /var/log/messages, but on docker /var/log/messages is empty.   I've tried setting the docker logging driver to syslog (in the docker run command) and I can see rsyslogd running in the docker container as well with ps -aux.

On my host machine, /var/log/syslog does not receive the logs either.
How do I get the log files to write to the /var/log/messages on the docker environment (or to my host machine, if storing them on the docker environment is not advisable)?
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Since docker does not support systemd, it's very likelly that syslog is not running on your container

My suggestion is... start a shell at your container
make sure syslog is installed using

yum list --installed

or

rpm -qa

Them run the syslog daemon from the shell manually
after that, start a new terminal and run your code

ps: since I'm on my phone, i can't be more helpful
I'll try to edit it as soon as possible